# SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol error in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I am implementing devise mailers for my application where i have done the following steps:

in model:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable, :confirmable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable
end
```

and then I added migrations of *confirmation_token, confirmed_at,
confirmation_sent_at*

In devise.rb, I added:

```
  config.mailer_sender = 'example@gmail.com'
```

In development.rb:

```
config.assets.raise_runtime_errors = true

  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'localhost:3000' }
  config.action_mailer.delivery_method = :smtp

  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
      :enable_starttls_auto => true,
      :address => 'smtp.gmail.com',
      :port => 587,
      :tls  => 'true',
      :domain => 'gmail.com',
      :authentication => :plain,
      :user_name => 'example@gmail.com',
      :password => '326272814example'
  }
```

When I click on forget password, I am getting the error as:

**OpenSSL::SSL::SSLError in Devise::PasswordsController#create**

**SSL_connect returned=1 errno=0 state=SSLv2/v3 read server hello A: unknown protocol**

through some links, I added:

```
 :enable_starttls_auto => false,
  :openssl_verify_mode => 'none'
```

to development.rb, but didin't helped me. Please help me out

Answer (score 0):

I think some of your smtp_settings are incorrect for gmail. Try

```
config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
  address:              'smtp.gmail.com',
  port:                 587,
  domain:               'example.com',
  user_name:            '<username>',
  password:             '<password>',
  authentication:       'plain',
  enable_starttls_auto: true  }
```

(From http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html#action-mailer-configuration-for-gmail)

Comment: i'm getting error `534-5.7.14 <https://accounts.google.com/ContinueSignIn?sarp=1&scc=1&plt=AKgnsbtMn`

Comment: From http://serverfault.com/a/636989: try enabling "Access for less secure apps" in your gmail account.

Comment: Create a password specific for the app, it's a more secure way.
Learn how to do it here: https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833?hl=en